# AppCompat theme losing all the blue title styling

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-styles, android-dialog

I have an AppCompatActivity containing a ListView that I am displaying as a Dialog (i.e. a list asking the user to take a photo or pick an image from the gallery).

However it says I must use `Theme.AppCompat` for the Dialog. So I use

```
<style name="CameraMenuTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
</style>
```

However the resulting title has a black color and no underline, in contrast to the blue text / blue underline that seems to show up in standard DialogFragments and the like.

How do I get that same theming back to this Dialog theme?

Edited with screen snippet:

[image]

I am invoking this new dialog from another DialogFragment by doing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CameraMenu.class);
intent.putExtra(TAG_1, stuff_1);
intent.putExtra(TAG_2, stuff_2);
startActivityForResult(intent, ACT_TAG);
```

Comment: any particular reason for using activity and displaying it as dialog? As what you are looking for can be achieved by using android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder, settitle and provide [setSingleChoiceItems](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems)

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I I'm in a DialogFragment by the time I give my user the choice to grab a pic from camera or gallery, and that choice is granted in the form of a ListView embedded in an Activity, and to get this Activity to display as a Dialog, I used a Dialog theme.

Comment: I use a ListView to display the choices because it allows me to effectively include icons for each option

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela My understanding is that `SingleChoiceItems` don't allow for fully customized item views like what you can do with ListViews (i.e. can't have icons next to the words like I have it in the screenshot)

Comment: If it is a case only for displaying icons and text for list item then for simple solution instead of passing SingleChoiceItems as string array you can use same adapter which you created in your activity. You are not getting desired title color because of the issue in DialogFragment style support. you have to use android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog to get things right

Comment: Sorry I'm not really sure what you mean. What do I have to change exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Create a Dialog without giving a style:

```
public static void showDialog(Activity activity) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        View view =  LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.dialog_common, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

Comment: I should have added that right now I am starting this Activity via an Intent. It's coded as an activity but it "looks like" a Dialog because of the theme (so instead of taking up the screen it hovers over everything in a smaller box)

Comment: what exactly you want then ? you want to show AppCompat dialog right?

Comment: It already shows up as a Dialog on account of using the Dialog theme, it's just that the title styling has been reduced to black instead of the typical blue-with-underline

Comment: @KaliMa Shoot your screen with whatever output you want for title or for dialog.

Comment: @jaydroider Added to post above with screenshot

Comment: remove style which have given in second parameter to dialog,

Comment: I am not quite sure where I would need to place that code or how I'd have it work with my Intent code that actually creates the activity / passes in Extra data (I updated my post)

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample theme for your dialog where colorAccent will be used for your buttons, textColorPrimary will be your title color and background is your dialog background.

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
  <item name="colorAccent">#0900FF</item>
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
  <item name="android:background">#FF0049</item>
</style>
```

Now add this theme to your application AppTheme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- your AlertDialog style -->
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

Now create your dialog. Here aa is your ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter whatever you used as adapter in your Listview.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().this);
    builder.setTitle("Dialog");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(aa, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int which) { 
       //which is index of your item clicked from the list. So take appropriate action.
     } 
    }) 
builder.show();
```

Comment: But what about the Intent arguments and setup? And the icons?

Comment: As you will be using the same adapter as you used for listview you will have sample display. Regarding Intent you can check **which** value and take appropriate action of displaying gallery or opening camera. No you do not require to open your activity. Instead display this dialog from your dialogfragment and implement your code.

Comment: Code crashes for me, it says on the builder.show(); line that there is a "Window leak"